# Pip3 showing different version of tensorflow library

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

When I do this

```
python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'
```

I get **1.3.0**

When I do this

```
pip3 show tensorflow
```

I get **1.8.0**

Why do I get different version of tensorflow on my same Ubuntu linux machine on paperspace.com

Comment: Does your pip3 associated python match your python3?

Comment: how can i check that ?

Comment: Just gave an answer for checking both `tensorflow` and `site-packages`. Please check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think you might have more than one python distributions in your system and your `pip3` associated python doesn't match your `python3`.

1. To check your "two" (potential) tensorflows:

   ```
   python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__file__)'
   ```

   and

   ```
   pip3 show tensorflow # And look for "Location: ..."
   ```
2. To check your `pip3` and `python3` associcated site-packages:

   ```
   python3 -m site

   #Or

   python3 -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages())"
   ```

   and

   ```
   pip --version
   ```