# pip list and tf.__version__ shows different tensorflow version

Tags: python, tensorflow

Snap shot of terminal:

[image]

I had installed 2 tensorflow versions

1. tensorflow-gpu ==1.6 (via pip install)
2. tensorflow == 1.8(via bazel build)

Now I have pip uninstalled tensorflow-gpu ,
 but when I try

'''
 tf.**version** 
'''

Ans = 1.6

and

'''
pip list | grep tensorflow
'''

Answer : 1.8

I have tried uninstalling 1.8 as well and reinstalling it

Comment: what is your actual question here ? pls have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: similar one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50291613/pip3-showing-different-version-of-tensorflow-library